# object has no attribute 'replace' trying to read a file.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before you say it's duplicated... I've read at least 15 other answers and couldn't make it...

I started getting this error while trying to replace an specific line.
Now it tells me it has no replace attribute... which it had at some point

I just need to add +1 to an specific line everytime a determinated event happens... and tried this.. which probably is a rough solution.

I saw some answers when they create a new file everytime, that wouldn't work since this event is supposed to happen all the time

so what am I asking here is... why the replace function isn't working... and/or  if there is another simpler function for what am I doing.

code:

```
usercidFile = str(usercid) +".txt"

with open(usercidFile,'r+') as uf:
    lines = uf.readlines()

    xName = str(lines[1])
    x = lines[4]    
    xx = lines[2]
    y = int(x)+1
    #it prints all vars until this point
    uf = uf.replace(str(x),str(y))
```

◙◙which wrings the following error:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bot.py", line 49, in listener
uf = uf.replace(str(x),str(y))
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Why were you expecting `uf` to have a `replace` method? What kind of object did you think you were working with?

Comment: `Before you say it's duplicated... I've read at least 15 other answers and couldn't make it...` The warning was scary

Comment: @Bola please read about how to deal with file objects in Python here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is not practical - in any language.

First, as others have said, there is no `replace()` method on a file object.

More importantly you don't seem to understand how text files work.  You say:  "*I saw some answers when they create a new file everytime*".  Did you consider *why* they do that?

*"I just need to add +1 to an specific line"*

Let's take a couple of lines in a text file that you *think* looks like this:

```
onetwomumble9
threefourmumble3
```

But a text file is nothing special, it just goes from the first byte to the last with newlines showing where lines end.   It really looks like this:

```
onetwomumble9\nthreefourmumble3\n
```

Where `\n` represents the single newline character.

Let's say that you did replace `9` with `10` and `3` with `4`.  The problem is that `10` is wider than `9` and the extra character will overwrite the newline (or any other character) which follows.  So you end-up with this:

```
onetwomumble10threefourmumble4\n
```

You lost the newline!

That's why you have to copy the file to update it!  The alternative is to use a database (like SQLite) which handles these issues.

There are a few work-arounds.  The simplest is to decide on an absolute maximum number of characters, and pad with zeros, for example `0009` gets updated to `0010`.

Let's say the file looks like this:

```
onetwomumble0009
threefourmumble0005
sixsevenmumble0067
eightnonemumber0042
```

For reading and writing to the same file, you have to maintain the file position yourself.  When you read a line it puts the current position to the next line, so to rewrite a line you have to move it back.
Example code:

```
import re
import sys

# Could be done as a one-line lambda, but would be difficult to read
def addit(m):
    num = m.groups()[0]
    new_num = "%04d" % (int(num) + 1)
    return new_num

line_number = 1

with open('gash.txt', 'r+') as uf:
    while True:
        start_pos = uf.tell()  # Get start of line position
        line = uf.readline()
        if not line : break
        end_pos = uf.tell()  # Get end of line position - needed if updating more than one line

        # Let's say we update line 2, and we decided on 4 chars
        if line_number == 2: 
            # Do the add
            newline = re.sub(r'(\d{4})$', addit, line)


            # Sanity check
            if len(newline) != len(line):
                print("line length changed!", line, file=sys.stderr)
                sys.exit(1)

            # Seek to start of line just read and write
            uf.seek(start_pos)
            uf.write(newline)
            # Seek to start of next line
            uf.seek(end_pos)

            # If we only wanted to update one line, we can:
            break

        line_number += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a `_io.TextIOWrapper` i.e. a file object will not have a replace method which is a string function. I think you're trying to make replacements in the entire file. Here is a quick fix.

```
file_data = ''.join(lines)
# Now apply your replacements here
file_data = file_data.replace(str(x),str(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to call `replace` method on a `file` object, whereas this is a `string` method.

Indeed :

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'r+')                                                                                   
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
>>> f.replace('test', 'no_test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'
>>> 'this is a test'.replace('test', 'no_test')
'this is a no_test'
```